# Вывести итоговое значение по всем строкам таблицы

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, база-данных, wpf

Доброго времени суток, возник такой вопрос по ADO.net. Я через c# выбираю из БД таблицу и вывожу её в datagrid. В таблице присутствуют одинаковые по смыслу строки. Например человек 2 раза положил деньги на телефон : первый раз 100р и второй раз 200р. Обе операции заносятся в таблицу под разными первичными ключами но значение ячейки в столбце `Вид операции` у обоих строк будет одинаковое `Пополнение баланса`. Теперь вопрос - как обратиться к базе (или как провести выборку в полученной таблице) что бы получить таблицу в которой вместо 2х строк со значениями 100р и 200р было одно но с итоговым значением в 300р ?

Comment: Почему вы не хотите объединить строки на уровне БД?

Comment: @vikolyada например, исходя из той же ситуации с пополнением баланса на телефоне - важно сохранять дату платежа.

Comment: Это понятно, хранить в БД можно подробную информацию, но запросом забирать уже в сгруппированном виде.

Comment: @vikolyada я о том и спрашиваю. как составить подобный запрос, если такое вообще возможно

Comment: В вашем случае необходимо использовать `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @vikolyada спасибо, буду курить мануал по GROUP

Comment: @Сергей: `select sum(amount) from orders group by userid, actionid`?